# LINQ Query - 2 dimensional Column

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, collections

I have a data table like below. Say I have thousands of records:

```
+----------------------+
| Col1          | Col2 |
+----------------------+
| Value1        | 1    |
| Value1,Value2 | 2    |
| Value2        | 3    |
| Value3,Value1 | 4    |
+----------------------+
```

`Col1` can have a single value or  value which is delimited by a special character (e.g.  ",").

I would like get the distinct values from `Col1` in a single LINQ query. I can do this in two steps, but I want it to be done in one step.

Can this be done, either as a list or an array?

Comment: I think Col2 should be just a little wider. :-P

Comment: So what would be your expected result? `Value1,Value2,Value3`?

Comment: yes, right it must be distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
var array = table
    .SelectMany(t => t.Col1.Split(','))
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
```